# Problem on idempotent finitely generated ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have a question.

Could you please help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance

> Let $\mathfrak a$ be a finitely generated ideal of $A$, commutative ring with identity, such that $\mathfrak a^2 = \mathfrak a$. Show that $\mathfrak a \subseteq Ae$ with $e^2 = e$, and $e$ is not identity.

Comment: You should add the hypotheses and details about what you want. As things stand, you can simply take $e=1$...

Comment: Sounds more like a command than a question. Do you want to know if the statement is true? Or do you know it's true but can't prove it? In any case, it's false. Consider $a=A=F_2$.

Comment: See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/297624/23500)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What follows is partially excerpted from my [Historia Matematica post of 2005\01\04](https://web.archive.org/web/20170423142208/http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=1111328&messageID=3648504) on this topic, in reply to questions by Colin McLarty and Martin Davis.

Below is a proof by Gilmer from a [Monthly Classroom Note[1]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316741).
Gilmer mentions it's also presented on p.58 of his [textbook[2]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824712420).$\:$
Remark that the use of Cramer's rule in Gilmer's proof is simply a special
case of the deduction of an equation of integral dependence over
an ideal (vs. ring), see Kaplansky, *Commutative Rings,* p.11 Exer.1.
or see his later Theorem 75, viz.

**THEOREM** $\rm\ 75.\ \ $ Let $\rm\:R\:$ be a ring, $\rm\:J\:$ an ideal in $\rm\:R,\ B\:$ an $\rm\:R$-module generated by $\rm\:n\:$ elements,$\ \ $  and $\rm\:r\:$ an element of $\rm\:R\:$ satisfying $\rm\ r\:B \subset JB\:.\ $ Then $\rm\ (r^n - j)\ B = 0\ $ for some $\rm\ j \in J\:.$

The desired proof now follows immediately, namely:

Specializing $\rm\ r=1,\ B=J\ $ yields $\rm\ (1-j)\ J = 0\ \Rightarrow\ J = (j),\ \ j^2 = j\:.\quad$ **QED**

Note that this may be viewed as a generalization of the simpler [Dedekind domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29454/242) case.

The above proof doesn't work in the noncommutative case
because the *determinant trick* no longer applies. However
one can prove Theorem 75 without using determinants by
instead appealing to Nakayama's Lemma. Namely, see Exercises 3.1, 3.2, p.43 in
Atiyah and Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*. Below is said direct proof of Gilmer - using Cramer's rule.

**LEMMA**  $\ $ If $\rm\:B\:$ is a finitely generated idempotent ideal of a commutative
ring $\rm\:T\:$ then $\rm\:B\:$ is principal and is generated by an idempotent element.

**Proof** $\ $ We first assume that $\rm\:T\:$ has an identity and we let $\rm\:\{b_{\:i}\:\}\:$ be a finite set of generators for $\rm\:B\:.\:$ Then $\rm\:B = B^2 = \sum\: B\ b_{\:i}\:$ so that we obtain a system of equations  $\rm\ b_k = \sum s_{\:k\:i}\ b_{\:i}\:,\ $ where $\rm\:s_{\:k\:i} \in B\:.\ $ This gives rise to a system of equations $\rm\ \sum\ (\delta_{\:k\:i}-s_{\:k\:i})\ b_{\:i} = 0\:,\:$ where $\delta =$  Kronecker delta.

By Cramer's rule $\rm\:d\ b_i = 0\:$ for all $\rm\:i\:,\:$ where $\rm\:d\:$ is the determinant of the matrix $\rm\ [\delta_{ki}-s_{ki}]\:.\ $ It is easy to see that $\rm\:d\:$ has the form $\rm\: 1-b\: $ for some $\rm\:b \in B\:.\ $ Since $\rm\ 0 = d\ b_i = b_i - b\ b_i\ $ for each $\rm\:i,\ B\ $ is the principal ideal generated by $\rm\:b\:.\ $ And since $\rm\:1-b\:$ kills $\rm\:B\:,\:$ we conclude $\rm\ (1-b)\ b = 0\:,\ $ or $\rm\ b = b^2\:.$

If $\rm\:T\:$ contains no identity element, we consider a commutative ring $\rm\:T'\:$ obtained by adjoining an identity element to $\rm\:T\:.\ $ Then $\rm\:B\:$ is a finitely
generated idempotent ideal of $\rm\:T',\:$ and hence is principal as an ideal of $\rm\:T',\:$ generated by an idempotent element $\rm\:v\:.\ $ Since $\rm\:T'$ is obtained by adjoining an identity element to $\rm\:T\:,\:$ it follows $\rm\:v\:$ also generates $\rm\:B\:$ as an ideal of $\rm\:T\:.\quad$ **QED**

[1] Robert Gilmer, [An Existence Theorem for Non-Noetherian Rings
(in Classroom Notes),](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316741)
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 77, No. 6, pp. 621-623.

[2] Robert Gilmer, [Multiplicative Ideal Theory,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824712420)
Queens University, Kingston, Ontario, 1968.  See p.58

Comment: Seealso [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/question-about-a-proof-on-atiyah-macdonald)