# Maximal ideal of Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be a Dedekind domain and $\mathcal{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $\Lambda$.

Is it possible that $\mathcal{m}=\mathcal{m}^2$?

If not, how can I prove it?

Comment: Wow, the site is really in good form tonight: three good answers all coming immediately.

Answer (score 8):

The ideals in Dedekind domains have unique factorization into products of maximal ideals.  The equation $m = m^2$ represents two distinct factorizations of $m$ ($m = m$ and $m = m^2$), which is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

A finitely generated idempotent ideal in an commutative ring is generated by an idempotent element (we dealt with this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25045/problem-on-finitely-generated-ideal) a little while ago), and this applies to your $m$ since $A$ is noetherian. There is then $e\in A$ such that $m=Ae$ and $e^2=e$. But then $(1-e)e=0$ and —since your ring is a domain,— we have either $e=0$ or $e=1$, that is, $m=0$ or $m=A$.

(Notice this requires much less than Dedekindness..)

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible.
The localisation $\Lambda_m$ is a principal ideal domain, hence $m\Lambda_m=t\Lambda$ for some prime element $t\in\Lambda$. The relation $m=m^2$ lifts to $\Lambda_m$ and yields $t\Lambda=t^2\Lambda$ in contradiction with the unique factorisation in $\Lambda_m$.

Answer (score 2):

Apply NAK Lemma to conclude that $(1 + x)\mathcal{m} = 0$ for some $x \in \mathcal{m}$. Now $R$ is a domain and $1 + x \neq 0$ since $-1 \not \in \mathcal{m}$. So $\mathcal{m} = 0$. which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Nonzero ideals in a Dedekind domain are invertible so cancellative, so if the domain is not a field, then $\rm\:m\:$ maximal implies $\rm\:m\ne 0\:,\:$ so $\rm\ m^2 = m\ \Rightarrow\ m = 1\:$ by cancelling $\rm\:m\:.$ In fact this generalizes to any ring. Namely, finitely generated idempotent ideals are principal, generated by an idempotent. See the three proofs in my [prior answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25045/problem-on-finitely-generated-ideal/25048#25048) using the determinant trick or integral dependence, and Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: When you write "In fact this remains true...", my best guess as a reader as to what "this" refers to is that nonzero finitely generated ideals in any ring are invertible.  As I know you know, this is not true, so I'm sure it's not what you meant...

Comment: @Pete: Obviously it refers to the generalization in the linked post.

Comment: It is not obvious to me, so it may perhaps not be obvious to someone else...

Comment: @Pete: I clarified the remark to eliminate possible misinterpretations. Thanks for mentioning it.