# Intersection of powers of the maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

There certainly exist commutative rings $R$ with unity containing a maximal ideal $m \subsetneq R$ such that
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty m^k \neq \{0\}.$$
(Thanks to Dietrich Burde, rschwieb and Lord Shark the Unknown.)

**Question:** What happens if we further assume that

(i) $R$ is an integral domain,

$\rightarrow$ (EDIT3:) No, see here: [Can an ideal in a commutative integral domain be its own square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246083/can-an-ideal-in-a-commutative-integral-domain-be-its-own-square).

or that

(ii) the quotient $R/m$ is finite?

$\rightarrow$ (EDIT2:) No, take $R = \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{F}_2$ and $m = \mathbb{C} \times \{ 0 \}$.

Or more general, is there a way to describe those rings $R$ such that $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty m^k = \{0\}$ holds?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18835/intersection-of-powers-of-an-ideal-in-a-noetherian-ring).

Comment: $F_2\times F_2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements is an example. I think I also gave two more relevant examples of local rings with idempotent maximal ideals [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2266545/29335)

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

How about the ring of continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$
and let $m$ be the functions vanishing at $0$? Then $f(x)=|x|$
is a $k$-th power of a function in $m$ for any $k$.