# $I^2=I$ but $I$ not a direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I\subset R$ an ideal. Let's give an example of a ring $R$ such that $I^2=I$ but $I$ is not a direct summand of $R$.

Given ring $R$ and ideal $I$, i know that if $I$ is a direct summand of $R$ then $I^2=I$ but i can't show the converse.

Comment: Is your ring assumed to be unital?  The claim that, if $I$ is a direct summand of $R$, then $I^2=I$ certainly fails for some non-unital rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be sufficient to find an integral domain with a nontrivial idempotent ideal, and that we done [at this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246083/29335) among other places.