# Proof of Proposition 2.4 in Atiyah-MacDonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm struggling here with the proof. To be honnest i need a really concrete explanation because i have been on it for a long time and i can not find it nowhere else.

[image]
Please can anyone help me with this? 
And thank you in advance.

Comment: See here for some details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma#Proof

Comment: It's very hard to be helpful if you don't tell us exactly where you stopped following the argument.

Comment: 1. You will get better results by describing your own difficulties rather than by insulting the source material.  2. You will also get better results by sharing which parts of the proof you are struggling with.

Comment: Also, if you are talking about Intro. to Commutative Algebra, it's worth calling it Atiyah-MacDonald. Or even using the title, because nowhere in the question is it said that $A$ is a commutative ring, so only if the reader divines your book can we figure out your question.

Comment: In the case of vector spaces over a field, finite-dimensional square matrices have a characteristic polynomial. This is a generalization.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42794/242)

Answer (score 12):

Consider the commutative subring $R=A[\phi]\subset\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ generated by $\phi$; then $R$ acts on $M$, and thus $M_n(R)$ acts on $M\oplus\cdots\oplus M$, the direct sum of $n$ copies of $M$. The equations
$$\phi(x_j)=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}x_i\,,$$
for $j=1,\dots, n$, can be reinterpreted with the action of $M_n(R)$ on $M^{\oplus n}$: write
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}-\phi & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots\\
a_{21} & a_{22}-\phi & a_{23} & \cdots\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}-\phi & \cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}\in M_n(R)\qquad\text{and}\qquad X=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}\in M^{\oplus n}$$
(To be very precise, we shoud actually write $a_{ij}\mathrm{id}_M$ everywhere instead of $a_{ij}$).
Then the $n$ equations we wrote at the start are equivalent to the one equation
$$B X=0$$
Since $R$ is commutative, we have $\mathrm{Adj}(B)\times B=\det(B)I_n=B\times\mathrm{Adj}(B)$, which is an equation which holds in $M_n(R)$. If we multiply the previous equation on the left by $\mathrm{Adj}(B)$, we get that
$$0=\mathrm{Adj}(B) B X=\begin{pmatrix}\det(B)\\&\det(B)\\&&\ddots\\&&&\det(B)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\det(B)x_1\\\det(B)x_2\\\vdots\\\det(B)x_n\end{pmatrix}$$
Since the $x_i$ generate $M$, this is equivalent to saying that $\det(B)$, which is an element of $R$, hence an endomorphism of $M$, **is the zero endomorphism of $M$**. The determinant $\det(B)\in R\subset\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ can be calculated by the standard formula
$$\det(B)=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}(-1)^\sigma\prod_{j=1}^nB_{\sigma(j),j}$$
which, upon inspection, is polynomial in $\phi$ of degree $n$ with coefficients in the ideal $\mathfrak a$. The coefficient in front of $\phi^n$ is $(-1)^n$, and since $\det(B)=0$, you get a relation
$$\phi^n+a_1\phi^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}\phi+a_n\mathrm{id}_M=0$$

Comment: @user26857 Cool :D, that's nice!

Comment: This is a super great answer. Atiyah and Macdonald were so ambiguous on the statement and proofs of this proposition, and I get really confused. Your answer makes all the things meaningful all of the sudden :)

Comment: Thank you @jacobsonradical !

Comment: I just want to say I came back to your answer several times. The first time I only grasped it for maybe 70%, next time for 90%, and now for 100%. I am very thankful for your careful explanation. Cayley-Hamilton has important corollaries, so I'm happy to be comfortable with the entire result (statement+proof).

Comment: Thank you very much @ShaVuklia : )

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that you are fine up to equation
$(1): \,  \sum_{j=1}^n (\delta_{ij} \phi -a_{ij} ) x_j=0, \, \, \, i=1,\dots,n$.
These equations can be represented in matrix form as
$(2): \, \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}=0$, where $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^\top$ and $\boldsymbol{C}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with $\boldsymbol{C}_{ij} = \delta_{ij} \phi -a_{ij}$.
If you wonder why (2) makes sense, note that the ring of endomorphisms of $M$ acts on $M$ in a way such that $M$ is an $\operatorname{End}_A(M)$-module. If you multiply from the left equation $(2)$ with the adjoint of $\boldsymbol{C}$, you will get
$(3): \,  \boldsymbol{C}^{\dagger} \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}=0$.
But matrix algebra extends to matrices over commutative rings (see Serge Lang's "Algebra" for this) and the well-known relation
$(4): \,  \boldsymbol{C}^{\dagger} \boldsymbol{C} = \operatorname{det}(\boldsymbol{C}) I$
still holds (again see Lang). Substitute this into $(3)$ and get that 
$\operatorname{det}(\boldsymbol{C}) \boldsymbol{x} = 0$, which implies that $\operatorname{det}(\boldsymbol{C}) M=0$.