# an idempotent ideal is generated by an idempotent?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, idempotents

How can i prove in a commutative ring that if an idempotent ideal I=Ra  and a is not contained in jacobson radical of R ,also a is not unitary,I is generated by an idempotent?

Comment: The proof is involved in showing if $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring with unity and $I^2=I,$ then the ideal $I$ is principal. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42727/finitely-generated-idempotent-ideals-are-principal-proof-without-using-nakayama).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let R be a commutative ring, and suppose $I = (a)$ is an idempotent ideal, i.e., $I^2=I$.

The goal is to show $I$ can be generated by an idempotent element.

Is that the correct problem?

If so, the proof is easy . . .
\begin{align*}
&I^2 =I\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(a)^2 =(a)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(a^2) = (a)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a = ra^2,\;\text{for some $r \in R$}\\[8pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Claims:}\\[4pt]
&(1)\;\;(a) = (ra)\text{.}\\[4pt]
&(2)\;\;ra\;\text{is idempotent.}\\[8pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Proof of $(1)$:}\\[8pt]
&ra \in (a)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(ra) \subseteq (a)\\[8pt]
&a = ra^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a = a(ra)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a \in (ra)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(a) \subseteq (ra)\\[8pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Proof of $(2)$:}\\[8pt]
&(ra)^2 =r(ra^2) = r(a) = ra\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Therefore the ideal $(a)$ has an idempotent generator, as was to be shown.

Note: I never used the part of the hypothesis relating to the Jacobson radical.

Comment: i think it should be used to show ra is not 0 ?

Comment: Either way, $ra$ is idempotent (since $0$ is idempotent).

Comment: Is this problem from a book?

Comment: No, my i was trying to read an article and i faced this...

Comment: Is it given that $I=(a)$ is an idempotent ideal?

Comment: Yes, I=Ra is idempotent

Comment: Then my proof should be OK as is. There's no need to mention units or Jacobson radical.

Comment: Yes , i think youbare right

Comment: @quasi 1) Some brackets used when work with elements bring confusion. 2) Some hints would have been in order.

Comment: @quasi doesn't the third implication use Nakayama?

Comment: @Arrow: No, just definitions. The element $a$ is an element of the ideal $(a)$, hence, since $(a^2)=(a)$, it follows that $a$ is a multiple of $a^2$.

Comment: @quasi ah, you're right of course. I was thinking of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42727/223002) where $I$ is not apriori principal.