# Use Nakayama's Lemma to show that $I$ is principal, generated by an idempotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a finitely generated ideal in $R$, such that $I^2 = I$. Using the fact there exists $x\in R$ such that $e = 1 - x\in I$ and $xI = 0$, use Nakayama's Lemma to show that $I$ is principal, generated by an idempotent.

Comment: could you please include some information regarding what you have tried so far, or whether your trouble lies in understanding NAK, how to apply it, etc...

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod Huh? The linked question says nothing about avoiding Nakayama's lemma, and one of the proofs mentioned in the answer does use the lemma.

Comment: @MathGems Sorry, I had someting else open in a new tab and I thought you linked to it where the question was asking to avoid the use of Nakayama's lemma. But I would agree, this can be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you know that by Nakayama's that there is an $x$ such that $1-x \in I, xI = 0$.
For any element $y$ in $I$ we have that
$$(1-x)y = y-xy =  y$$
Which means that any element $z \in I$ can be written in the form 
$$(1-x)z\in R$$
which gives the inclusion $I \subseteq (1-x)$ and the inverse inclusion comes from the fact that $1-x \in I$. We also have idempotence because
$$(1-x)(1-x) = 1-x$$
By our first claim. Therefore $I = (1-x)$  and satisfies all listed properties.